# SSH connection through Python cannot run Shell scripts

Tags: linux, ssh, shell, python

I have a `Shell` script on a `Linux` machine that I have to execute. The only connection I am able to do is over `SSH` but it won't run the script.

So I have an application that actually has to do this so below is my code:

```
    client = SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect("myHost", username="myUsername", key_filename="SSH_Key_Location")
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command("/test.sh -h")
    print(f'STDOUT: {stdout.read().decode("utf8")}')
    print(f'STDERR: {stderr.read().decode("utf8")}')
```

The code above establish the connection successfully and sends the command. The problem is that nothing happens, it gets stuck. I tried with some test Shell scrips as well and it's the same problem

There are 2 weird things:

1. Using a terminal to connect using SSH and run manually the command will work just fine (using same credentials)
2. There are 2 connection nodes setup. The second node doesn't have this service I'm trying to execute but it can run Shell scripts (I've tried with some test scripts).

What can be a hint or an issue that can cause something like this to happen? There is a team that takes care of them, but I am not sure what to ask them to check.

Things I have tried so far:

- Using different libraries (SSHLibrary, Paramiko)
- Trying to run `/test.sh -h`
- Trying to run `sh /test.sh -h`
- Trying to run `cd / && test.sh -h`
- Trying to run `cd / && sh test.sh -h`
- Trying to run `/usr/bin/sh test.sh -h`
- Trying to run `cd / && /usr/bin/sh test.sh -h`
- Trying all above for a different Shell script (just for testing)
  All of them behave the same, no results, no actions.
- Trying to run a simple command like `cd /etc && ls` -> THIS WORKS

Again, in the terminal works, and the script works fine on the other connection node on a test `sh` script(but there I don't have this service and it's not up to me to set it up there).

Comment: "The problem is that nothing happens, it gets stuck" where does it get stuck? I'm guessing this is Python code, right? So when you run it line by line, what do you get see? On which line does it stop? And what is the full path of the `test.sh` script on the remote host? Are you sure your local Python code is calling the right script?

Comment: It gets stuck after the `.exec_command`. Looks like when trying to print the returned messages waits forever. But there is another weird thing. If I remove the `print` statements, the script goes to the finish (all good) BUT the script Shel script run on the linux machine doesn't have any effect

Comment: But if I go to terminal, connect with same credentials over SSH, run manually the same script (basically copying the command from the code and paste it in the terminal) it works fine

Comment: Did you try with the dot,. e.g. `./test.sh -h`? Did you try `sh /full/path/to/test.sh -h`? Please [edit] your questions to indicate what you've tried.

Comment: I've updated the question with things that I've tried to far

Comment: Nice, thanks. Can you try `./test.sh -h` (with a dot at the beginning). Also, can you try  `.exec_command('pwd')`  to see where in the filesystem the SSH session gets you when you login from Python?

Comment: Trying `./test.sh -h` returns `No such file` and it makes perfect sense because the default location where the scripts is connected is `/home/myUser` and the script is in the root location at `/`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the contents of test.sh (or some other shell script that demonstrates the same problem).

Comment: you can consider both containing an `echo "test"`. One of them used only for testing contains exactly that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem.

Whenever I try to run a script, it asks for my password (a strange setting from the IT Team). So my script was not able to run the commands for the scripts (but it was able to run other commands that didn't require a password or additional confirmations. So this applies for anything you want to do that requires user's input after the command (like y/n or password or giving paths and so on)

So if you ever encounter this problem, try to look into the logs (that's where it was displayed in my case that the password was not provided)

And the solution in terms of the script I used to send additional commands (any input you need for specific actions like: password, y/n, etc)

```
 client = SSHClient()
 client.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())
 client.connect("myHost", username="myUsername", key_filename="SSH_Key_Location")
 stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command("/test.sh -h")
 stdin.write("yourAdditionalInfo\n") # Don't forget about the \n; This line can be used multiple times, to send multiple lines
 stdin.flush() 
 stdin.channel.shutdown_write() #! This is really important. Without closing the write channel, the lines sent with **write** will not have effect
 print(f'STDOUT: {stdout.read().decode("utf8")}')
 print(f'STDERR: {stderr.read().decode("utf8")}')
```

Comment: Nice find! Didn't the test.sh script ask for a password when you ran it directly in the terminal over SSH?

Comment: No, that's where the problem was. Connecting over cygwin would establish a session that allowed running those scripts but using the python script the session was a little bit different and it couldn't be checked properly, so it asked for the password